# Função não está sendo executada quando a página carrega

Tags: javascript

O código em JavaScript abaixo deveria exibir uma janela de alerta com a frase "Hello World!" quando a página index.html fosse carregada, mas isso não acontece... O conteúdo da página carrega, mas a função não executa.

```
var main = function () {
  'use strict';

alert("Hello World!");
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que está errado com ela?

```js
var main = function () {
  'use strict';

alert("Hello World!");
};

window.onload = main;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Simple App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <section class="comment-input">
      <p>Add Your Comment:</p>
      <input type = "text"><button>+</button>
    </section>
    
    <section class="coments">
      <p>This is the first comment!</p>
      <p>Here's the second one!</p>
      <p>And this is one more.</p>
      <p>Here is another one.</p>
    </section>

    

    <script scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Só uma chamada de atenção, o título da pergunta não tem nada a haver com nada, muito menos com o problema... tenta aplicar um título que clarifique o problema em mãos.

Comment: A pergunta é essa por que é isso que quero saber... Não sei muito sobre javascript e ainda não sei muito bem o que estou fazendo...

Comment: Você sabe que está usando jQuery? Era sua intenção?

Comment: sim, carreguei a jQuery 2.1.3... vou postar o código que usei no html...

Comment: `scr` deveria ser `src`... vem de _source_ em Inglês. Ou seja, onde tens `<script scr=`, muda para `<script src="`

Comment: Sim, agora funcionou... Muito obrigada!... ^_^ Desculpe a dúvida boba... mas é como eu disse, não sei muito sobre javascript... :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O teu código funciona perfeitamente, ver o exemplo em baixo:

```js
var main = function() {
  'use strict';

  alert("Hello World!");
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Agora, se não tens o jQuery carregado, vais obter um erro do tipo:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Erro este que vai fazer com que o código de JavaScript na tua página deixe de funcionar.

Deverás incluir o jQuery antes desse código ser lido:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var main = function() {
    'use strict';

    alert("Hello World!");
  };

  $(document).ready(main);
</script>
```

No caso de não estares a fazer uso do jQuery, tens que alterar o teu código da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(main); // documento pronto
```

Deve passar a:

```
window.onload = main;    // documento pronto JavaScript puro
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var main = function() {
  'use strict';

  alert("Hello World!");
};

window.onload = main;
```

Comment: Ou `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);`, que é o que o jQuery faz (exceto em browsers não compatíveis).

Comment: Bom, na página index.html carreguei a jquery 2.1.3 e a função acima em arquivo separado, chamado app.js e chamei no index.html, mas no final do arquivo, seguindo um exemplo que estava usando... antes de fechar a tag body...

Comment: @VanessaRibeiro E o ficheiro foi lido pelo navegador? Para testar podes meter como primeira linha desse ficheiro o seguinte: `alert("Ficheiro lido");`. Se esse alerta aparecer então o ficheiro está a ser lido, o que quer dizer que voltamos ao problema do jQuery e o facto do mesmo estar ou não estar a ser carregado na página.